# AIC versus AICvlm in the VGAM package in R

Tags: r

The `VGAM` package in `R` contains the function `AICvlm`, which is different from the `AIC` function in base `R`.  Here is an example of the difference:

```
require(VGAM)
fit = vgam(agaaus ~ s(altitude, df = 6), binomialff, data = hunua)
AICvlm(fit)  # I get 386.7385
AIC(fit)     # I get 395.2227
```

I am confused by the documentation page on `AICvlm`.  Specifically, the examples section includes only sample uses of the `AIC` function with no mention of `AICvlm`.  So, do we have here (a) a mistake in the documentation or (b) a bug in the code or (c) something else?

Comment: The documentation pretty clearly implies that `AICvlm` is unfinished and/or experimental, and further seems to warn that AIC may not be a wise metric for such models generally.

Comment: @joran, I noticed this.  Nevertheless, I'm wondering if there is any way in which it can make sense for the examples on the page about AICvlm to include only AIC.

Comment: @joran yes, but `fit` is not of class `"vglm"` so on top of all those other warnings, it isn't even *intended* to be used on an object of `fit`'s type. I suppose `AICvlm()` should ideally be hidden in the NAMESPACE, but the Examples are pretty clear about calling `AIC()` and not some other function...

Comment: Especially in light of these comments, I also find it odd that typing `?AICvgam` brings up the help page for `AICvlm`.

Comment: @zkurtz That is unfortunate (actually it is an `\alias{}` in the Rd markup - all such methods will point to that page), but the usage section is truly unfortunate. Perhaps email Tom Yee to mention this documentation infelicity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fit` is of class `"vgam"` and hence `AIC()` will dispatch to the `AICvgam()` function via the S4 method for `AIC()` with signature `"vgam"`:

```
R> getMethod(AIC, "vgam")
Method Definition:

function (object, ..., k = 2) 
AICvgam(object, ..., k = k)
<environment: namespace:VGAM>

Signatures:
        object
target  "vgam"
defined "vgam"
```

I suspect that the (supposedly) internal function (`AICvlm()`) works at all in this case (i.e. does not throw an error) is due to the `"vgam"` class having all the components of a `"vglm"` classed object (plus some others). Anyway, as the *Examples* show you, use the `AIC()` generic and let the author of the **VGAM** sort out the particulars for you.

In answer to your specific question: *c) something else*. In particular, user error.